# Wordpress send ajaxrequest to admin-ajax.php is not working?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Dear Friends This is my code to the send post request.

```
$.post("<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",{'action':'add_content'},function(result){
        if(result == "add0"){
            $(".success").show();
        }else{
            $(".error").show();
        }
});
```

this is my function to get request in functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_content', 'ajax_add_contactlist' );

function ajax_add_contactlist() {
    echo "come";
}
```

this code is working successfully when user is login.

but user is not login then it return 0. and not call that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass below line for non logged in user

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_content', 'ajax_add_contactlist'); // Not logged in user
```